# Django ManyToManyField referencing self: Rendering to template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Below is the code for a project I'm working on. As you can see in the view, I'm running a query for objects in the Risk model that are associated with the primary key in the Url.

The problem is that I can't access the attributes of the object being queried.

**Model**

```
class Risk(models.Model):
    risk_title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    root_causes = models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                         through='Roots',
                                         symmetrical=False,
                                         related_name='root_cause')


class Roots(models.Model):
    causal_risk = models.ForeignKey(Risk, related_name='causes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    effected_risk = models.ForeignKey(Risk, related_name='effected_risk', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**View:**

```
def view_risk(request, id):

    try:
           risk = Risk.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Risk.DoesNotExist:
           raise Http404("Risk does not exist")

       roots = Roots.objects.filter(effected_risk=id)


    args = {
        'risk': risk,
        'roots': roots,
       }
return render(request, 'risks/risk_detail.html', args)
```

**Template:**

```
{% for root in roots %}

{{ root }}

{% endfor %}
```

Running the above code returns this:

```
Roots object (2) Roots object (3)
```

This should be expected, as these are the entries I've made to the model through the admin interface.

However, when I run:

```
{% for root in roots %}

{{ root.risk_title }}

{% endfor %}
```

The screen is left blank.

**TLDR**
Passing the query from the intermediary table to the template works, but the template can't access the object attributes. How can I run the above query and then access the objects in the template?

**UPDATED**Included the render portion per JoJo's response. This problem has been solved per my other update.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please fix indentation in `view_risk`. Also, what does this function return exactly?

Comment: Done. It's a function based view for a Django application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the view function is missing the `return` statement, so there is actually no html page rendered at all.

Assuming that the template html is named `'my_template.html'`, the missing `return` should look something like:

```py
def view_risk(request, id):
    # ...
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', args)
```

Further, as @JonHrovat mentioned, the template needs to call

```
{{ root.causal_risk.risk_title }}
```

within the for loop.

***A note on efficiency***:

If you call `root.causal_risk.risk_title` within the template with your current query for `roots` this leads to additional queries, one for each iteration. This can be avoided by using the [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) statement when querying for the roots in the view function:

```py
roots = Roots.objects.select_related('causal_risk__risk_title').filter(effected_risk=id)
```

Comment: Updated, thanks but the main problem was the template itself.

Comment: @JonHrovat the template is not even called, if there is no `return` statement.

Comment: thanks, I've updated the original post. I had forgotten to copy that part over, but I had it in my original code.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info about select-related, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to query the direct attributes of the model. I got what I need with this template:

```
{% for root in roots %}

{{ root.causal_risk.risk_title }}

{% endfor %}
```